# Why does my function return a different value depending on where it is called?

Tags: c, string, function, memory, embedded

I have to compose a string in this manner:

```
char message[200];
uint32_t device_id = get_raw_device_id(); // returns an internal FICR register value
char some_string[50];

/* Some intermediary code to populate some_string and open an MQTT connection. */

int len = snprintf(message, sizeof(message), 
        "{\"device_id\": \"%08X\", \"Params\": \"%s\"}",
        device_id, some_string);
```

When printing "message", I always get : {"device_id": "6501000A", "Params": "XXXXXXX"}.

Here's the code for get_raw_device_id():

```
#define     __IM     volatile const      /*! Defines 'read only' structure member permissions */

typedef struct { 
....
  __IM  uint32_t  DEVICEID[2]; /*!< (@ 0x00000060) Description collection: Device identifier  */
....
} NRF_FICR_Type;

uint32_t get_raw_device_id()
{
    return NRF_FICR->DEVICEID[1]; // Only getting one of the 32bit values for brevity
}
```

device_id is supposed to be a hex value 0x6501C74F.
This is fixed when I arrange the code like this instead:

```
char message[200];
char some_string[50];

/* Some intermediary code to populate some_string and open an MQTT connection. */

int len = snprintf(message, sizeof(message), 
        "{\"device_id\": \"%08X\", \"Params\": \"%s\"}",
        get_raw_device_id(), some_string);
```

Something about moving the function call to the string composition line fixes the problem, but I'm not sure why this happens.

Comment: You skipped too much context code, everything looks like an attempt at initialised global variables. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Double-check that you really used `snprintf` instead of `sprintf`.

Comment: What does `Some intermediary code` do?

Comment: Perhaps you are putting too much into `some_string`. Does it end with `'\n'`? ;-)

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is `NRF_FICR`? Where and when do you set it? What does "// Only getting one of the 32bit values for brevity" mean? Did you change for the example? What do you do in your real code? Please edit your question to post the MRE requested already above.

Comment: My magic ball tells me that "intermediary code" changes `device_id`. Maybe your "some_string" is not long enough to hold the content and you overflow into neighbor variables. But the image is a bit blurred due to too many missing code.

Comment: Problems where moving the code around but not changing it seems to "fix" the bug are often caused by stack overflow.

Comment: Most likely a buffer overrun of `some_string` in the unseen intermediate code.

Comment: We know nothing about what you are doing with `NRF_FICR`.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `device_id` has been changed from `0x6501C74F` to `0x6501000A`, which is consistent with its first 2 bytes having been overwritten with `0x0A` and `0x00`.  This could come from a buffer overflow where the string stored into `some_string` would exceed the length of the array and the trailing newline `'\n'` and the null terminator overwrite the initial part of `device_id` (as commented by @the_busybee).

You should investigate the elided portion of code summarized as `/* Some intermediary code to populate some_string and open an MQTT connection. */` for possible buffer overflows.  Posting this code should get you a more precise answer.